# php updated, but still old OpenSSL version...(Mac OS X Server)

Tags: php, openssl

I tried updating an old php-version (5.4.3) on mac OSX server because I need a newer version of OpenSSL (eg. 1.0.0 or 1.0.1). Updating php went succesfully, but the old version of OpenSSL is still in this php version...

I used this for updating php:
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6

How Can I install this version with newer OpenSSL  (at least 1.0.0) included?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Install the openssl version that you want. Openssl is independent from php

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. A newer version of OpenSSL is installed, but How Can I make that version is used by PHP? Or is it possible to let Apache Or PHP now which version of OpenSSL Should be used?